# After a bug is resolved in bugzilla, I don't find the bug existing anymore. How could I access it?

Tags: bugzilla, quick-search

Once the bug is set `RESOLVED`, the bug is completely removed from my bugs. I wanted to keep a track of the number of issues resolved. How could I see it and get back all in one list?

Comment: `ALL` is your friend, please see my answer.

Answer (score 14):

Go to any "Search" page and make sure "Status" is set to "all" (or whatever).  The default is usually "open" and that's why you're not seeing your closed bugs.  If you open the "Advanced" tab of the search, you can drill down very precisely.

Answer (score 3):

Your search criterion "Resolution" may have value "---" which is a value, not a wildcard. Complicating things, usually web browsers don't give you an obvious way to deselect the only selected value in a multiselect list such as this one.

**Fix**:

You can deselect the "---" value of the "Resolution" search field by holding down the Ctrl key and clicking on the "---" value.

That works in Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Chrome. If I recall correctly it works in Safari as well, or maybe that uses Command or Option modifier keys instead of Ctrl.

Of course this fix doesn't apply to mobile devices. Long press? I don't know.

Alternatively there's nothing wrong doing like in Excrubulent's answer: work around this difficulty by selecting all of the values in the Resolution list.

Answer (score 3):

Actually my BzDeck app [1] had the same issue. It was showing My Bugs in the main Inbox thread pane, the core feature of the app, but bugs would suddenly disappear when it's been RESOLVED. My solution was adding a selector to display all/open/closed bugs [2].

There are two different scenarios:

- People usually would like to focus on open bugs (bug if they are involved in too many bugs, the My Bugs list could be very long), however,
- People sometimes continue discussing on closed bugs (on BMO, RESOLVED FIXED for Firefox bugs only means the patch has been committed to the source code repository)

Given that, a better, possible solution would be:

- Distinguish clearly open bugs from closed bugs like GitHub issues (this applies to the all UI on Bugzilla; GitHub issues use green and red icons for this purpose [3])
- Provide a selector like BzDeck to switch between all/open/closed bugs, showing all bugs by default
- Load/show the bug list lazily to improve performance

As mentioned, My Bugs was the core of BzDeck as well as another experimental Bugzilla client called Buggy [4], and I believe Bugzilla should also implement the same thread sidebar so people can go though their bugs much faster.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1380026

Answer (score 0):

Searching under the advanced tab for resolved bugs doesn't work in some versions of Bugzilla.  See this bug on the Bugzilla *Bugzillaception*:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663377

That bug says resolved for 4.2.1, but I'm using 4.2.5 and it isn't fixed for me, so apparently your mileage may vary.  I've mentioned this issue on that bug.

A potential workaround for now is to search for various resolution values (FIXED, WONTFIX, WORKSFORME, etc).  Anything with those values set should have a status of resolved or verified.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the *quick search*, `ALL` is your friend, this word has to be typed at the very beginning of the input line and overrides the status criterion (as can be found in: [*Examples of Simple Queries*](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/page.cgi?id=quicksearch.html#basic_examples)).

BTW: Bugzilla's quick search can also be added to the Browser's search engines and combined with a keyword also within its address bar. <sup>(confirmed for Firefox and Edge)</sup>

I warmly recommend the 5½-minute summary in [*Bugzilla Quicksearch will BLOW YOUR MIND*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14W-XguG--U) on YouTube.